# Convert a unixtime to a datetime object and back again (pair of time conversion functions that are inverses)

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, dst

I'm trying to write a pair of functions, `dt` and `ut`, that convert back and forth between normal unix time (seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) and a Python datetime object.

If `dt` and `ut` were proper inverses then this code would print the same timestamp twice:

```
import time, datetime

# Convert a unix time u to a datetime object d, and vice versa
def dt(u): return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(u)
def ut(d): return time.mktime(d.timetuple())

u = 1004260000
print u, "-->", ut(dt(u))
```

Alas, the second timestamp is 3600 seconds (an hour) less than the first.
I think this only happens for very particular unixtimes, maybe during that hour that daylight savings time skips over.
But is there a way to write `dt` and `ut` so they're true inverses of each other?

Related question: [Making matplotlib's date2num and num2date perfect inverses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259875/making-matplotlibs-date2num-and-num2date-perfect-inverses)

Comment: btw, if function does nothing but calls another function with the same arguments then you could just assign it: `dt = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp`. Functions are first-class citizens in Python: you can pass them  as parameters to another functions, return from functions, etc.

Comment: Ah, nice, great point! Is it more efficient to do so or just a matter of succinctness? What about `def f(x): return foo(x)` vs `f = lambda x: foo(x)`? (My recollection is that those are equivalent, both functionally and efficiency-wise.)

Comment: `f = g` means that f,g are two names that refer to the same function. `def` and `lambda` create new function.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You are correct that this behavior is related to daylight savings time.  The easiest way to avoid this is to ensure you use a time zone without daylight savings, UTC makes the most sense here.

[`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) and [`calendar.timegm()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) deal with UTC times, and are exact inverses.

```
import calendar, datetime

# Convert a unix time u to a datetime object d, and vice versa
def dt(u): return datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(u)
def ut(d): return calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
```

Here is a bit of explanation behind why [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) has an issue with daylight savings time, from the docs:

> Return the local date and time corresponding to the POSIX timestamp,
>   such as is returned by `time.time()`. If optional argument tz is None or
>   not specified, the timestamp is converted to the platform’s local date
>   and time, and the returned datetime object is naive.

The important part here is that you get a naive `datetime.datetime` object, which means there is no timezone (or daylight savings) information as a part of the object.  This means that multiple distinct timestamps can map to the same `datetime.datetime` object when using `fromtimestamp()`, if you happen to pick times that fall during the daylight savings time roll back:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1004260000) 
datetime.datetime(2001, 10, 28, 1, 6, 40)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1004256400)
datetime.datetime(2001, 10, 28, 1, 6, 40)
```

Comment: [`ut = lambda naive_utc_dt: (naive_utc_dt - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, want to add that as an answer? It sounds like you're right (though I haven't verified your version) and yours should be the accepted answer here. I hate to lead posterity astray, with only a link in the comments pointing to a better way!

Comment: @dreeves: follow the link to see more details. timegm()-based solution is ok if you don't need microseconds