# How to read those tuple and convert int type during forloop?

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, unix-timestamp

I want to change tuple type data into int type during forloop.
How to read those tuple data?
(Because I want to convert those data into datetime )

```
>>> print data
((1424794931452.0,), (1424794931645.0,), (1424794931821.0,),(1424794932014.0,), (1424794932189.0,))
```

I have 5 tuple data(unixtime) and this is what I want to do.

```
for i in data:
    con = int(data[i][0])
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(con // 1000)
    s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(s)
```

I think those tuple data is ([0][0],[1][0],[2][0],[3][0],[4][0]) right?

What is problem? I don't know python well.

Comment: Check out the answer given by @AndrewClark [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260863/convert-a-unixtime-to-a-datetime-object-and-back-again-pair-of-time-conversion) for problems that fromtimestamp can cause (others have already answered your use of i problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a tuple containing single element tuples.  You probably want something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = ((1424794931452.0,), (1424794931645.0,), (1424794931821.0,),(1424794932014.0,), (1424794932189.0,))

for elem in data:
    con = int(elem[0])
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(con // 1000)
    s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(s)
```

Output:

```
2015-02-24 11:22:11
2015-02-24 11:22:11
2015-02-24 11:22:11
2015-02-24 11:22:12
2015-02-24 11:22:12
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that i is the element in data, not an index. So you should do:

```
for i in data:
    con = int(i[0])
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(con // 1000)
    s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is already a sub-tuple, not an index in `data`. So its enough to do:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = ((1424794931452.0,), (1424794931645.0,), (1424794931821.0,),(1424794932014.0,), (1424794932189.0,))

for i in data:
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(i[0] // 1000)
    s = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(s)
```

Result is:

```
2015-02-25 00:22:11
2015-02-25 00:22:11
2015-02-25 00:22:11
2015-02-25 00:22:12
2015-02-25 00:22:12
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for x in y` syntax, x gets assigned to the elements of sequence on every iteration. To enumerate over the indexes, you would have to use the built-in function `enumerate` which returns both the indexes and the items.

I would do something like this instead:

```
for con in (int(d[0]) for d in data):
    do_something_with(con)
```